# GET request working on Postman but not code on Terminal

Tags: python, curl, terminal, postman

I am running a GET on Postman and worked fine with Status 200 ok, but when I pick up the code from Postman and running the Curl/Python on my Mac OS terminal it through a 401 error, can you please help me fix the issue.

curl --location --request GET 'www.instacart.com/v3/containers/costco/next_gen/retailer_information/content/delivery?source=web' --header 'Cookie: _instacart_logged_in=1; build_sha=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; signup_load_perf_date=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; amplitude_idundefinedinstacart.com=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; _gcl_au=xxxxxxxxx; _fbp=fbxxxxxxxx;......'

{"error":{"message":"Unauthorized"},"meta":{"triggered_action":null}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of your command you posted seems OK.

Maybe you missed other headers?
Take into account the cookie may be expired as well...

UPDATE:

The server can ban curl user-agent, so try to add

```
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla' \
```

In addition, Postman may automatically append Content-Type header, so try to add

```
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
```

Another thing is to check the host. Try with `https://` and maybe with/without `www`

Comment: I repeatedly tested for multiple runs with new cookies, and the code I am picking up is from postmaster itself

Comment: @Kumar I updated my answer, please try the both additions

Comment: if i add only -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla' \ i am seeing the following error  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   162  100   162    0     0    292      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   292
100    69    0    69    0     0     77      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    77
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Cookie

Comment: It seems your host is not good. Try with `https://`and maybe with/without `www`

Comment: It worked like a charm!!!! Thanks!!!! https://www.instacart.com/v3/containers/costco/next_gen/retailer_information/content/delivery?source=web

Comment: @Kumar Cool, please accept my answer . I updated it again.